# Mouse wheel won't scroll 100% of the time in file system

Tags: mouse, xfce, mouse-scroll, nemo

I'm running  XFCE Desktop Environment, with the default Window Manager and am using Nemo File Manager.

I love everything about this setup, except one thing: I can't scroll through my files like I want to. When I'm focused on either the left panel where all my drives are listed, or focused on the files, when I move my mouse wheel: nothing.

This is remedied by moving it off to the side until that 'virtual scroll nub' appears, then mouse wheel works perfectly. In every other setting and application that I can think of, it scrolls properly.

Also, this is a logitech USB mouse.
 I would like to do two things:

1. Make my mouse wheel scroll all the time a window in my file system
   has focus
2. This one is optional, but kinda nice: make a fat scroll bar off to
   the side that is always there, and not just popping up when I move
   to the side.

It also exhibits this behavior in PDFs with the default PDF viewer, the 'document viewer'

Comment: This seems like an issue with Nemo, especially since your report that this is the only app where you encounter the issue. And it would be useful if you could provide a screenshot of what happens.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/FaWMJ Here's screenshots of with and without the scroll bar.

Comment: Don't add the "solved" tag to the title.  You should take the solution, post it as an answer to your question and then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just click on Settings --> Window Manager Tweaks --> Accessibility --> raise windows when any mouse button is pressed, I Unchecked that, and it works PERFECTLY.  See image below.

[image]